# cannot write to file if I run .exe

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am writing a short program where I want to write an array full of street names to a .txt file. Everyting works fine, but if I convert the python code to a .exe with pyinstaller, I cant write to a new .txt file anymore. Why does this happen?

```
    with open(f"C:\\Users\\auser\\Desktop\\tset\\{txtname}.txt", "a") as txt_file:
        for line in new_addresses:
            txt_file.write(line + "\n")

    txt_file.close()
```

this is how I create the .exe:

> pyinstaller --onefile streets.py
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "streets.py", line 65, in 
> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\Users\auser\Desktop\tset\test.txt'
> [7048] Failed to execute script rewriteword

Comment: `I cant write` - what's the error?

Comment: The .exe closes immediately

Comment: Run `exe` from command line. You'll see error message.

Comment: I added the error into my question

Comment: Close `C:\Users\auser\Desktop\tset\test.txt` if it is opened. Run your `exe` as admin.

Comment: still the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work now. My anti virus program was blocking for some reason the execution.